# Get a conflicting declaration error when pass a string to the constructor

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that takes a path from the user and copies the file.

When I try to start the program, I get following error:

`error conflicting declaration 'File path'`

Why can't I pass the path as a parameter to the constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class File
{
   char path[255];
   FILE *in;

public:
   File(char path[255])
   {
       char letter;
       scanf("%s", path);
       in=fopen(path, "rb");
       FILE *out;
       out = fopen("test.txt", "wb");
       while(!feof(in)) {
           letter=fgetc(in);
           fprintf(out, "%c", letter);

       }
   }

};
int main()
{
   char path[255];
   scanf("%s", path);
   File(path);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. The method should be called File() not PPM(). I have forgot to change this. I get the same error after changing.

Comment: I've revised it now.

Comment: I needed a while to get the logic and make it a running MCVE but finally I did. -> It worked: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3ce9bbe1d576e8e). What's the issue on your side? Did you debug step-wise?

Comment: @Scheff But you also added a variable name between `File` and `(path)` - which fixed the problem.

Comment: You are kind of abusing a constructor as free function here. That's not the point of constructors or classes and probably not what you want to do.

Comment: @AdrianMole Oops! I did it without thinking about. I even was not aware that this is essential but I see it is. :-)

Comment: @Scheff Changing `File(path);` to `File{path};` would also work - but I think that would just be encouraging bad code.

Comment: I'm a total beginner and didn't know how to debug. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @AdrianMole Unfortunately, there is much more I had to complain about... E.g. `while(!feof())` or usage of C API in C++ or usage of plain C array instead of `std::string`.

Comment: What OS platform are your using? What IDE or compiler?

Comment: The error message was certainly longer than what's quoted in the question. Error messages contain important information. Don't summarize them.